Power BI measure doesn't respect filter context in the Matrix visual
I have a table in Power BI where I have the weekly sales amount by account for past 3 months. My date column is week_started_at which is the start of given week. I have added a column called WeekRank to rank each week. I'd like to calculate W/W change of total sales by account. But my DAX measure doesn't respect the filter context despite having ALLSELECTED. Can you help me understand why this measure fails to respect the filter context when added to a matrix visual:
Imagine I have a table with these columns:



account
sales_amount
week_started_at




123
$20
2024-03-24


123
$40
2024-03-31


123
$60
2024-04-07



current_week_sales = COALESCE(
    CALCULATE(SUM(table[sales_amount]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table), table[WeekRank] = MAX(table[WeekRank]))),0)

last_week_sales = COALESCE(
    CALCULATE(SUM(table[sales_amount]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table), table[WeekRank] = MAX(table[WeekRank]) -1)
    ), 0)

W/W_Change = 
VAR weekly_comparison = [current_week_sales] - [last_week_sales]
RETURN 
COALESCE(
    IF(ISBLANK(weekly_comparison), "", DIVIDE(weekly_comparison , [last_week_sales]))
    ,0)

The measures work fine as long as they are added to a tabular visual but they don't work as expected in matrix. None of the measures respect the filter context in the matrix, as result all values are the same week over week for all accounts.
Would you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?
The expected outcome is the matrix view of this data in Power:

P.S
Figured the solution:
Modify the measures to this:
current_week_sales = COALESCE(
    CALCULATE(SUM(table[sales_amount]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table[WeekRank]), table[WeekRank] = MAX(table[WeekRank]))),0)

last_week_sales = COALESCE(
    CALCULATE(SUM(table[sales_amount]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table[week_started_at]), table[WeekRank] = MAX(table[WeekRank]) -1)
    ), 0)


what's the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

I just added more text to the Description to explain the outcome. I can't quite build the matrix view in the text editor here on Stackoverflow but just assume the Matrix visual where Account is at Rows field, Week_started_at in Columns field, and measures are in Values field.

then you can write in excel and paste the screenshot. That will be helpful to understand the request.

I was able to fix the issue with current_week_sales by changing to                                     current_week_sales = COALESCE(
CALCULATE(SUM(table[sales_amount]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table[WeekRank]), table[WeekRank] = MAX(table[WeekRank]))),0)
But the same solution doesn't work for last_week_sales

Oh I figured the issue with last_week_sales measure, I had to modify the DAX to this: COALESCE(
CALCULATE(SUM(table[sales_amount]), ALLSELECTED(table[week_started_at]), table[WeekRank] = MAX(table[WeekRank]) -1)
, 0)
